# Strange (and random) error in Mongo replicaset running on K8S

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I used the helm mongo chart with `-set architecture=replicaset` so I do have

```
pod/mongo-mongodb-0           1/1     Running   0               6h15m
pod/mongo-mongodb-1           1/1     Running   0               6h15m
pod/mongo-mongodb-arbiter-0   1/1     Running   0               6h15m
```

managed by:

```
service/mongo-mongodb-arbiter-headless 
service/mongo-mongodb-headless
```

I have pods connecting to mongoDB via `pymongo`. I've noticed that sometimes write operations such as `find_one_and_update` fail with the most bizarre error:

```
pymongo.errors.NotPrimaryError: not primary, full error: {'errorLabels': ['RetryableWriteError'], 'topologyVersion': {'processId': ObjectId('638f137760787a4a2c889597'), 'counter': 3}, 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'not primary', 'code': 10107, 'codeName': 'NotWritablePrimary', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1670343147, 130), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xce\xa6_4\xe8H_G\xa5\x06\xf1\xe1\x1a?\x88\xd1\x01\x7f,\xa5', 'keyId': 7173973884128422279}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1670343147, 130)}
```

I am not sure why this happens randomly. But it seems to be either MongoDb isn't very stable in replicaset mode, or I'm doing something very wrong. Some questions:

1. Is his situation similar to trying to write to a read replica? from python we only conncet to `service/mongo-mongodb-headless` -- should I be connecting to `service/mongo-mongodb-arbiter-headless`?
2. Is there anything I can add to the write call to make sure it ONLY uses the primary?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but I've had great reliabiliy using https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator for MongoDB on Kubernetes. It does a lot of the heavy lifting that can trip you up leading to the type of errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You connect to the replica set, i.e. all members of the replica, excluding arbiters.

The error should be handled by the driver. From https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/179efda31200b495beab6c2e94f365f5713aadc4/pymongo/topology.py#L665

> ```
> # As per the SDAM spec if:
> #   - the server sees a "not primary" error, and
> #   - the server is not shutting down, and
> #   - the server version is >= 4.2, then
> # we keep the existing connection pool, but mark the server type
> # as Unknown and request an immediate check of the server.
> # Otherwise, we clear the connection pool, mark the server as
> # Unknown and request an immediate check of the server.
> ```

It happens right after or during re-election, when driver is not aware that previous primary stepped down.

All writes go strictly to primary. Reads can go to secondaries, if configured. By default all reads go to primary too. If the request arrives to secondary, it respond  with this error to notify driver that topology has changed. It should retry the operation with new topology by sending request to new primary.

Please corelate app logs with mongodb logs for RCA.